# Define a url for an email confirmation from within a plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I'm making a plugin where the user can order something. But before he has to confirm his email, so I'm sending out that mail with the confirmation link, something like that: `mydomain.com/myconfirmation?token=MYTOKEN`

How do I fetch this confirmation url `myconfirmation` in WordPress without the website owner having to create an extra page for this?

Comment: You don't need an extra page; just any .php file that can parse the query selector from the URL, and take the appropriate action (including redirect to a "you have confirmed" page...which you really should do in examples like this).

Comment: Ok, you mean simply link to a .php file in my plugin folder? But what if I need wp-specific functions? Just include the needed wp files? Is that the best-practice for my case?

Comment: Link to `http://example.com/?confirmation_token=TOKEN`, then use an action handler on `template_redirect` that listens for this parameter. When it exists, do something - you'll have the WordPress environment loaded and you don't need to do anything else other than handle the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert in your `functions.php` file the following code

```
function order_confirm_token()
{
    if(isset($_GET['myconfirmation']))
    {
        $confirmation_token = $_GET['myconfirmation'];

        // Do something with token
    }
}
add_action('init', 'order_confirm_token');
```

Then when you send the user the email to confirm the email direct them to the home page like this:

`www.example.com/?myconfirmation=TOKENCODE`

Answer (score 0):

Link to `http://example.com/?confirmation_token=TOKEN`, then use an action handler on `template_redirect` that listens for this parameter.

When it exists, do something - you'll have the WordPress environment loaded and you don't need to do anything else other than handle the request.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function () {
    if ( ! $token = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'confirmation_token' ) )
        return;

    // do something

    // Redirect without confirmation_token
    wp_redirect( remove_query_arg( 'confirmation_token' ) );
    exit;
});
```